# In Data.Pool, what happens if the action that creates a new resource throws an exception?

Tags: haskell, pool

In [Data.Pool](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool-0.2.3.2/docs/Data-Pool.html), `createPool`'s first parameter is the "action that creates a new resource".

What happens if this action throws an exception? Can I control what happens? (I'm afraid it will go into an infinite loop where it continually tries to create a new resource.)

(For the `withResource` function, they say: "If the action throws an exception of any type, the resource is destroyed, and not returned to the pool." But this seems like an entirely different thing. This seems to happen *after* the resource has already been successfully created. So I guess this is not a clue to the answer to my above question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resources aren't created until you `takeResource` or `tryTakeResource` and there isn't a resource in the pool. If the action to create a resource throws an exception the pool is left unmodified and the exception is raised in the calling code. If you repeatedly call `takeResource` or `tryTakeResource` even when previous calls have thrown exceptions the create action will be executed repeatedly. [`withResource`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool-0.2.3.2/docs/src/Data-Pool.html#withResource) calls `takeResource` without handling any exceptions; if the action to create a resource throws an exception in `takeResoure` the exception will be raised in the code calling `withResource`.

---

The code that creates a resource is in [`takeResource`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool-0.2.3.2/docs/src/Data-Pool.html#takeResource) and [`tryTakeResource`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/resource-pool-0.2.3.2/docs/src/Data-Pool.html#tryTakeResource). The difference between them is that when `used == maxResources` `takeResource` `retry`s; `tryTakeResouce` returns `Nothing`.

When there are no available entries, and `used` isn't `maxResources`, they both do the following:

```
create `onException` atomically (modifyTVar_ inUse (subtract 1))
```

When an exception occurs creating the resource the number of resources `inUse` isn't changed and the exception is raised in the code calling `takeResource` or `tryTakeResource`.